# jQuery UI Widget factory calling _hoverable (etc.) multiple times

Tags: jquery-ui

In a widget, I'm adding a `refresh` method and I need to cleanup everything before re-applying all the hooks. However, I'm not sure what are the consequences of calling `this._hoverable(selector);` multiple times on the same elements.

Looking inside `jquery-ui-1.10.js`, I see that the widget factory keeps a jQuery object of the elements, and it performs an `add` operation with the selector. While I assume it wouldn't add duplicate DOMelements, it's more the next operation : `_on` that makes me doubt.

Is it ok to call `_hoverable` and such multiple times on the same element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not do that. Calling [_hoverable()](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_hoverable) more than once on an element will register additional handlers on the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

If you absolutely have to call this method more than once, you will have to unbind these handlers beforehand:

```
this._off(element, "mouseenter mouseleave");
this._hoverable(element);
```

Note the events are namespaced under the hood, so the call to `_off()` above will only unbind the handlers registered through `_on()`, not additional handlers you may have registered yourself.

Comment: I just spent quite a long time looking for the info in your "Note the events..." section. Are there docs somewhere that cover these kind of details? The jquery ui api docs are pretty scarce.

Comment: @slicedtoad, you may be interested in reading the [widget factory section](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) of the documentation. The part about the `_on()` method there mentions the namespacing, among other details.